# "Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined" when I use new ServerStyleSheet

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-dom, server-side-rendering

I get the `Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined` error when I try to instantiate the `ServerStyleSheet` but it works fine without it.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  color: blue;
`;

const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Wrapper />);
```

Comment: maybe This link can help you - https://lifesaver.codes/answer/uncaught-error-cannot-create-styled-component-for-component-undefined